# Add-in Development

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to find out more about developing apps/add-ins  (on premise)

I will be tasked to write some farm solutions as add-ins but at the moment I think add-ins are nowhere near replacing farm solutions.
For example: I am trying to do a new and improved Announcement custom list as an app, but I discovered that the list I create in to the app only exist in app web, but what I want to do is add the actual custom list as an app to the host web. I am having woes to create my custom list template inside the host web.

There are bits of information online on how to do this, thanks to blogs and stack overflow, but am I missing something or is the documentation is surprisingly minimal about apps/add-ins(especially on premise)?

I have already been through: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163794.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164084.aspx

Can you please share resources about 2013 add-in development, I am really struggling to find helpful resources.

Comment: Also do you guys recommend getting an O365 subscription for app development / personal development reasons. I have a VM which I use at home to develop my skills. What I am really scared of is getting the subscription then finding out 'oh something is not compatible, you can't deploy add-ins' type of issue. Even configuring on-premise apps were a pain. The way SP2013 marketed was : oh the development was going to be much more easier.I get it, the list designer in VS and everything is cool but I still cannot get the app development and see many people are like me.I think it's still difficult :(

Comment: Personal opinion: The Addin model does not work (yet). I have 2 Apps in the Store for 16 months and had 3 sales.. If you are on the learning track start with JavaScript, JSOM, REST, those are the technologies you need to understand 100%... If you start the other way around.. "Developing an Addin and learning JS,JSOM,Rest along the way" will cause a lot of frutstration. I am now moving my Addins to (opensource) CSR development with [iCSR](http://icsr.github.io)